# svg sprites without output on html

Tags: html, css, svg, sprite

I've recently been introduced to svg sprite and I decided to try it out for the first time on my current project but I'm dead sure there's something missing and I just cant figure it out even after reading some documentations and tutorials.

the sprite

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
 <defs>
   <symbol id="icon-github" viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
     <title>Github Icon</title>
     <path d='M.184 10.462c-.779 4.906 1.401 10.823 8.123 13.006.12.022.231.032.335.032.782 01.32-.582 1.32-1.3-.097-.523.383-2.642-.92-2.357-2.519.536-2.821-.871-3.205-1.607 1.086 1.394 2.718 1.359 3.949.819.683-.3.326-1.064.65-1.343a.75.75 0 00-.407-1.314c-2.314-.255-4.457-1.001-4.457-4.702 0-2.168 1.505-2.362 1.09-3.269-.015-.033-.333-.754-.045-1.849 1.419.262 2.072 1.28 2.753 1.097 1.687-.46 3.544-.46 5.23 0 .704.189 1.207-.801 2.738-1.103.441 1.654-.473 2.058.103 2.677.632.68.953 1.503.953 2.447 0 5.564-4.717 3.957-5.101 5.22a.748.748 0 00.235.792c.61.513.53 1.83.465 2.889-.067 1.098-.125 2.045.482 2.579.214.19.595.393 1.284.253 6.634-2.131 8.83-8.022 8.063-12.917C21.726-2.856 2.296-2.84.184 10.462zm8.27 10.978l.004.505a11.811 11.811 0 01-1.475-.623c.425.109.913.156 1.471.118zm.37-3.7l-.015.08c-.853.252-1.509.001-1.957-.752l-.001-.002c.68.364 1.381.56 1.973.674zM12 2c11.833 0 14.502 16.267 3.469 19.941-.038-.297-.003-.857.021-1.252.058-.951.126-2.059-.213-2.985 5.088-1.059 5.513-6.646 3.554-9.135.243-.952.145-3.189-.729-3.463-.206-.065-1.305-.304-3.437 1.037a11.657 11.657 0 00-5.361 0c-1.064-.667-3.462-1.752-3.922-.6-.534 1.342-.407 2.427-.248 3.03-1.739 2.204-1.218 5.894.534 7.626-.993-.475-2.361-.637-2.656.314-.323 1.037.912.911 1.679 2.804.073.236.208.513.415.788C-1.705 14.54 1.581 2 12 2z'></path>
   </symbol>
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="container__footer">
  <a class="container__button" href="https://github.com/" target="_blank">
    <svg class="container__icon">
      <use xlink:href="../_src/sprites/defs.svg#icon-github"></use>
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

Any possible mistake I might be making?

Comment: Your svg is malformed. At the very least you are missing the closing svg tag.

Comment: https://iconify.design/icon-sets/logos/github-icon.html
plesae refer this and makes code proper closing

Comment: Is the url of the sprite file correct for the **compiled** page, or for the source jade file (which would be wrong)?

Comment: Please read about [How SVG Fragment Identifiers Work](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/)

Comment: Thank you all! @RayeesAC and Lee Taylor helped me figure out that the svg path was malformed, indeed. 

One last thing. I got just a snippet from the whole sprite and that's the reason the <svg> and <defs> elements were not closed. Thank you anyway